# Bulk rename and move files in Perl

Tags: perl

I’m searching for a way to rename each found `.seg` file to include the name of a folder two directories above the `.seg` file.

For example I found a `.seg` file in

```
/data/test_all_runs/TestRun/Focus-HD753/QC/diffCoverage.seg
```

and would like to rename it

```
Focus-HD753.seg
```

Once I renamed the file I would like to move it to

```
/data/test_all_runs/TestRun
```

or  `$ARGV[0]`. Here is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;
use File::Spec;

my $home = "/data";
my @location_parts = ($home, 'test_all_runs');
push @location_parts, $ARGV[0] if @ARGV;
my $location = File::Spec->catdir(@location_parts);

my @moves;
my @vcf_moves;
sub find_seg {
    my $F = $File::Find::name;
    if ($F =~ /\.seg$/ ) {
        my @path_parts = File::Spec->splitdir($F);
        my $name = $path_parts[-3];
        my $target = File::Spec->catdir($location, "$name.seg"); print $target;
        push @moves, [ $F, $target ];
    }
}   
find({ wanted => \&find_seg, no_chdir => 1 }, $home);

while (@moves) {
    my ($F, $target) = @{ shift @moves };
    warn "$F -> $target";
    rename $F, $target or warn "Can't move to $target";
}

sub find_vcf {
    my $V = $File::Find::name;
    if ($V =~ /(vcf$|oncomine\.tsv$)/ ) {
        my @path_parts = File::Spec->splitdir($V);
       print "The path_parts at 0 is #############".$path_parts[0]."\n";
       print "The path_parts at -1 is #############".$path_parts[-1]."\n";
       print "The path_parts at -2 is #############".$path_parts[-2]."\n";
       print "The path_parts at -3 is #############".$path_parts[-3]."\n";
       print "The path_parts at 1 is #############".$path_parts[1]."\n";
       my $target_vcf = File::Spec->catdir($location, $path_parts[-1]); print $target_vcf;
      push @vcf_moves, [ $V, $target_vcf ];
      print "$V\n";

    }
}

find({ wanted => \&find_vcf, no_chdir=>1}, $home);

while (@vcf_moves) {
    my ($V, $target_vcf) = @{ shift @vcf_moves };
    warn "$V -> $target_vcf";
    rename $V, $target_vcf or warn "Can't move to $target_vcf";
}
```

Comment: Normally it is expected that you tell us what's not working in your current code... i.e. what you don't understand.

Comment: Do you want to move it to "or $ARGV[0]" or "concatenated with $ARGV[0]"?

Comment: actually, I need to move the renamed .seg file to "TestRun" which is one directory down from "test_all_runs". The name of this folder will always be different but /data/test_all_runs will always be the same. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [rename](http://p3rl.org/rename) to move a file to a name destination and name. 
[File::Spec](http://p3rl.org/File::Spec) makes the code OS independent. You can also check [Path::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Path::Tiny) for similar tasks.

The moves are saved in an array and excuted later, otherwise File::Find might move the same file several times as it walks the directories.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;
use File::Spec;

my $home = "/data";
my @location_parts = ($home, 'test_all_runs', 'TestRun');
push @location_parts, $ARGV[0] if @ARGV;
my $location = File::Spec->catdir(@location_parts);

my @moves;
sub find_seg {
    my $F = $File::Find::name;

    if ($F =~ /\.seg$/ ) {
        my @path_parts = File::Spec->splitdir($F);
        my $name = $path_parts[-3];
        my $target = File::Spec->catdir($location, "$name.seg");
        push @moves, [ $F, $target ];
    }
}

find({ wanted => \&find_seg, no_chdir => 1 }, $home);
while (@moves) {
    my ($F, $target) = @{ shift @moves };
    warn "$F -> $target";
    rename $F, $target or warn "Can't move to $target";
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to move a file while ’F:F’ is in progress?

Comment: @PerlDog: Hm, good question. Probably not :-) You can [push](http://p3rl.org/push) the file paths to an array and process it afterwards.

Comment: @PerlDog: Updated. I tested the old script and it moved the file twice in some cases.

Comment: @choroba. I get an error Can't stat data: No such file or directory at `find({ wanted => \&find_seg, no_chdir => 1 }, $home);` thanks

Comment: @user3781528: Sorry, missing `/` before `data`, as my system doesn't have `/data`.

Comment: the only thing that worked was  `#my @samplename = (); @samplename = split /\//, $F; print "The sample name is #############".$samplename[4]."\n";
        #my $final_location = $location.$samplename[4]."\.seg";
        #copy $F, $final_location;` which is not great and I would prefer to use a more sophisticated method like yours.

Comment: Sorry, the second time I ran the code it worked great.  I can't understand why. The first time I ran it there were no errors but the files were not move/renamed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it possible to search the sub directories for other types of files (.vcf and .tsv) simultaneously in the same routine without renaming them.  I would like also to search for .vcf/tsv files and move them to the same directory as the renamed .seg without renaming the .vcfs/.tsvs Thanks

Comment: @user3781528: Why not? Just store them into the @moves array, too, using the old name (`$path_parts[-1]`) instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Also, it's dumping the renamed .seg files into "test_all_runs" but I would like to move them to "TestRun" folder instead. thanks

Comment: @user3781528: Fixed.

Comment: Please clarify if the code is looking for .seq/.vcf files in a sub directory of "test_all_runs" or not?  Because I just accidentally moved hundreds of the vcf files from all the folders located in \data directory and not in "test_all_runs" folder. I'm going to have to manually copy and paste them back somehow. Please tell me how to change the code it it `copies` instead of `moves`. please ...

Comment: but why did it moved files from all folders in `/data`? thanks

Comment: If you don't walk the whole `/data`, don't specify `$home` as the second parameter to `find`.

Comment: you are saying it should be `find({ wanted => \&find_seg, no_chdir => 1 }, $home."/test_all_runs");` correct?

Comment: `File::Spec->catdir($home, 'test_all_runs')` to keep it consistent.

Comment: Ok this worked. Thank you for a great lesson. hopefully IT will be able to restore the server to what it was yesterday. :)

Answer (score 0):

For the name file name modifications you could use [`File::Basename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) module, which is part of the core.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{say};
use File::Basename;

my $filePath = "/data/test_all_runs/TestRun/Focus-HD753/QC/diffCoverage.seg";
my ($filename, $directories, $extension) = fileparse($filePath, '.seg');

my $target = (split m{/}, $directories)[-2];
say "Target: $target";

my $newFilePath = "$directories$target$extension";
say $newFilePath;
```

Result:

```
Target: Focus-HD753
/data/test_all_runs/TestRun/Focus-HD753/QC/Focus-HD753.seg
```

Then you can move it using `$ARGV[0]`  to the location you want (maybe with [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) ?)

Comment: it didn't rename the file for some reason. I've posted the entire code with your suggestions.  Please take a look, Thanks